# Why is state apparently changing when the view is loaded?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a view where I created an enum that has some values in it, one of which is "SHOW_LOGO", I have a few composables on the screen and I want to show different ones based on what the use does.  For instance, my initial state is "SHOW_LOGO", when the screen first loads, I see the logo for just an instance, then something happens like maybe the screen finishes loading and then the logo dissappears, which to me means that something has changed the value of my enum from "SHOW_LOGO" to "SHOW_DETAIL"

Can anyone tell me what is updating my enum?  Code is below:

The enum:

```
enum class AddReturnViewState {
    SHOW_LOGO,
    SHOW_BARCODE_WINDOW,
    SHOW_DETAIL,
}
```

My composable:

```
@Composable
fun AddReturnItem(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: ReturnsViewModel,
) {

    var scannedCode by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
        handleColor = OrangeTextFocusedColor,
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    )
    val addReturnViewState = remember { mutableStateOf(SHOW_LOGO)}

  


    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
        ) {
            IconButton( // Scan UPC with Camera Button
                onClick = {
                    if (addReturnViewState.value == SHOW_LOGO ||
                        addReturnViewState.value == SHOW_DETAIL) {
                        addReturnViewState.value = SHOW_BARCODE_WINDOW
                    } else {
                        addReturnViewState.value = SHOW_LOGO
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_barcode2),
                    contentDescription = "Scan with built in camera button",
                    tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) DarkModeIconTint else LightModeIconTint,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp)
                )
            }

            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors,
            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = scannedCode,
                    onValueChange = { scannedCode = it },
                    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 17.sp),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                        .onFocusChanged {
                            addReturnViewState.value = SHOW_LOGO
                        }
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                        .onKeyEvent { keyEvent ->// bluetooth scanner or hardware keyboard
                            if (keyEvent.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                                processScannedCode(
                                    navController,
                                    viewModel,
                                    scannedCode,
                                ) {
                                    addReturnViewState.value = it
                                }
                                scannedCode = ""
                                focusManager.clearFocus()
                            }
                            true
                        },

                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                    ),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions( // soft keyboard
                        onDone = {
                            keyboardController?.hide()
                            processScannedCode(
                                navController,
                                viewModel,
                                scannedCode,
                            ) {
                                addReturnViewState.value = it
                            }
                            scannedCode = ""
                            focusManager.clearFocus()
                        }),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        cursorColor = OrangeTextFocusedColor,
                        focusedIndicatorColor = OrangeTextFocusedColor,
                    )
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        if (addReturnViewState.value == SHOW_LOGO) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(64.dp))
            AsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(SettingsHelper.getLogoUrl(LocalContext.current))
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build(),
                placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sls_logo),
                contentDescription = "Image of distribution center logo",
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
            )
        }

        if (addReturnViewState.value == SHOW_BARCODE_WINDOW) {
            Log.d(ADD_RETURN_ITEM, "‼️ Showing BarcodeFragment")
            AndroidViewBinding(DecoratedBarcodeContainerBinding::inflate) {
               barcodeFragmentContainerView.getFragment<BarcodeFragment>()

                if (viewModel.barCodeScannerResult.value.isNotBlank()) {
                    processScannedCode(
                        navController,
                        viewModel,
                        viewModel.barCodeScannerResult.value,
                        ) {
                        addReturnViewState.value = it
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (addReturnViewState.value == SHOW_DETAIL) {
            ReturnItemDetailView(
                navController,
                viewModel,
                enableTrashButton = true,
                enableActionButtonRow = false,
            ) {
                addReturnViewState.value = SHOW_LOGO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the SettingsHelper class and the function that is relevant:

```
public class SettingsHelper {

public static String getLogoUrl(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferencesRef(context);
        if (sp != null) {
            return sp.getString(LOGOURL, "");
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional information, I have the feeling that it has to do with this line:
.data(SettingsHelper.getLogoUrl(LocalContext.current)).  I replaced it with .data(R.drawable.testLOGO), and that logo doesn't disappear.
So that makes me think that it has to do with the "SettingsHelper.getLogoUrl()" function that I am calling, so I am adding the listing for that class/function.  Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.
What was actually happening was: in my AsyncImage, it was actually initially showing my placeholder and then once the call to SettingsHelper completed that was coming back with a url string the resuted in a 404 error.  So the AsyncImage resolved to blank.

My solution was to log on to my server and drop the correct image in the location that was being sent back to me.  (I debugged and saw that the url returned was the url I was expecting)